# Vagrant 'vv create' gives 404 Not Found nginx error

Tags: nginx, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

Problem with Variable VVV....I have Variable VVV installed and running. When I run `vv create` it creates the directory and the database (and reports success) but does not transfer the Wordpress folders and files to the directory. When I attempt to access the directory I get a `404 Not Found nginx` error. The only files which exist in the directory are `vvv-hosts`, `vvv-init.sh`, `wp-cli.yml`. I am on Windows 10 running Git Bash as administrator. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

What appears to be happening is that when the `vv create` command is run, the 'htdocs' folder with the expected WordPress files are not being installed. To solve this problem, I [ran this solution](https://github.com/bradp/vv/issues/324#issuecomment-260541817) found on Brad Parb's vv Github Issues:

> `cd dev/vagrant-local` # Use location of vagrant-local on your machine
>
> `vagrant ssh`
>
> `cd /srv/www/Your-Site-Name`
>
> `./vvv-init.sh`

Comment: Thank you, Greg. I've been beating my head against the wall trying every configuration I could think of. Also searching for every variation on Variable VVV and htdocs(I did figure out the problem) but never found this solution.

Thanks very much for saving my workflow.